# Black Desert Linking Nodes

Tags: black-desert-online

Black Desert is kind of new but I already have a question.

The node system links different nodes together, one after the other.
Now there are different connections: those that are active because you invested in them, and others (in a light white) which sometimes work and sometimes don't.

So can someone explain to me, when does the white line appear between nodes and do they just link (white connection) if I invest contribution points?

I would like to have all nodes linked together so I know if I'm missing one or not but I'm not certain if that means that I need to "activate" all links or if it's their normal state not to be linked til I invest points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every node has connections to one or more other nodes. When you discover a node, you will see white lines that show its connections to these other nodes (but you will only see the connection if you've also discovered the node that it's connected to).

When you first discover a node, it is useless to you. You can't do anything with a node until you activate it. You can only activate nodes that are either:

1. Connected to a city or town that you've discovered
2. Connected to a node that you've activated

This means that you'll have to start at the city/town, and activate nodes in a chain out to the node you're interested in. Nodes that you've activated are displayed in yellow, and the connections between nodes you've activated are also shown in yellow.

Activating nodes has a variety of effects, including:

- You can assign workers to gather from a node you own.
- You can invest energy in a node you own to improve drops from monsters you kill in that area.
- Warehouse transport is significantly cheaper if you have activated the nodes in a path between the two locations.
- Profit from trading is significantly increased if you have activated nodes in a path between the two locations.

Answer (score 0):

The white lines show that connection is possible and to which nodes but once you invest your contribution points the line between connected nodes will be highlighted in yellow/gold.

Connecting to all nodes will be a waste of your points, try finding the most direct routes and those which have the worker stations available for mining gathering and such, but trying to connect all nodes will leave you unable to continue into new areas because there is waaay to many ways to use your points like upgrading storage, room for workers, housing, and such to use all the nodes.